# Game Center Leaderboard showing counts, put no scores

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, game-center

I have recently added game center to my application and everything worked great in testing.  Now, when I release the app, I went and and played the game, had a high score and submitted it.

I actually have three leader boards:  North America, Europe and World.  If I click on the leader boards, it does show that I am 1 of 1 users, top rank but when I click on the Daily, weekly, Overall, it does NOT show up any users.

Is/was there something else I needed to do when I moved it to production?  I can't seem to see why the counts for leader board users is correct, but no actual scores or users are displayed.  Any one have an idea?

Geo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is an iOS 5 issue. I just had this problem, tested on an iOS 4 device (and with another account) and now my scores show up on both devices.

Comment: Real weird - I'm experiencing the exact issue. @James: when you use it on an iOS 4 device and go back to your iOS 5 device, do scores get updated properly again or do you constantly have to go back to the iOS 4 device to get the latest scores to show? Also - does anyone know if this is because your app is approved for sale but you are testing it prior to the availability date? That's the scenario I'm in.